# Where should the data "live" in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, struct

Trying to make a WPF app following the MVVM pattern (first time attempting it). I've read plenty of tutorials/articles on MVVM, but not sure if I quite get it. One question in particular I have is: **where does the actual data live?**

For instance, my app is going to read binary files into structs, and the GUI will display things based on the fields in those structs.

Where would those structs go and the functions that read the binary files into those structs? In the model? ViewModel? Normally I'd just put it all in the codebehind of the MainWindow, but that obviously isn't the MVVM pattern.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Data will "live" on the View, you can move your structs and such in your viewModel , also have logic to combine multiple model properties.

Comment: I don't think I can explain it better than Reed Copsey, that why I leave a [link to his article](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/06/better-user-and-developer-experiences-from-windows-forms-to-wpf-with-mvvm-part-7-mvvm/) here (used it when learn MVVM myself)

Comment: Structs and functions that read them would go in the model. The viewmodel presents the information in a way the UI can consume (INPC, ObservableColletion, etc.) and exposes Commands for the UI to manipulate it.

Comment: The data should live in the model and at the model layer. The UI is a "way of looking at the model" and the viewmodel is the bridge between the two.

Comment: "Structs" are model(s)/part of model(s). Code, that reads/writes binary files and turns them into "structs",  is a service(s), which should be injected into view model.

Comment: "Data will 'live' on the view" is amateur hour thinking even in winforms. In XAML it's an even worse idea. The view displays a view of the data.

Comment: Adapters to decode the binary structs either go in the model layer or the viewmodel layer, depending on whether it is an inherent way of decoding the struct (model layer) or something specific to facilitate the bridge to UI (viewmodel).

Comment: As said, the data should be stored in the Model, with the ViewModels passing them through. Which makes `struct`s a very strange (and probably wrong) choice. As Value types they will be copied instead of linked to. Any good reason they're not classes?

Comment: Hmm I guess they could be. The person the app is for is used to Delphi and packed records and wanted to 'mimic' them by using structs. Class would probably be better. Thanks for the responses everyone!

Comment: Delphi uses classes too. This must hark back to Turbo Pascal. Times they are a changing.